# Laravel Octane + nginx subdomain: How to set up nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, laravel-octane

I have the following route in my web.php

```php
$parsedUrl = parse_url($appUrl);
$host = $parsedUrl['host'];
Route::domain("{slug}.$host")->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', IndexController::class);
});
```

So when an user access client1.mywebsite.com the 'client1' is passed as the slug to IndexController.

Everything works fine but im trying to use octane and I cant figure it out how to setup my nginx to  make it work.

When I dont need to get the subdomain, I usually do this:

```
location /index.php {
    try_files /not_exists @octane;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @octane;
}

location @octane {
    set $suffix "";

    if ($uri = /index.php) {
        set $suffix ?$query_string;
    }

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000$suffix;
}
```

How can I configure my nginx to accept a dynamic subdomain and pass it to octane?

Answer (score 0):

what I did to work was removing this additional  "$uri/" at location directive:

FROM

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @octane;
    }
```

TO

```
location / {
        try_files $uri  @octane;
    }
```

this way octane worked properly with subdomains

heres the full nginx config

```
location /index.php {
    try_files /not_exists @octane;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri @octane;
}

location @octane {
    set $suffix "";

    if ($uri = /index.php) {
        set $suffix ?$query_string;
    }

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000$suffix;
}
```

Comment: I have the same config, but I wonder about the if statement. Why is this needed?
Why not always send the $query_string to the proxy_pass?